# How change query value (where : { }) with Apollo GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

with graphQL we can fetch data with "where"

```
query{
  activities(where: {date: "2020-08-01"}){
    date
    collect
  }
}
```

How change the date value to params ?

I try this :

```
let date = "2020-01-08"
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ACTIVITY, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        where: { date: date }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Any arguments like `where` are specific to whatever schema you are querying. GraphQL provides no built-in way to filter or sort data -- it's up to each individual service to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

First the [schema definition](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/schema/) from your back-end must be something like this:

```
type Activity {
  date: String
  collect: String
  ...
}

type Query {
  activities(date: String): [Activity]
  ...
}
```

then in the front-end create the query using the `gql` function from `@apollo/client`:

```
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

...

const GET_ACTIVITY = gql`
  query Activities($date: String!) {
    activities(date: $date){
      date
      collect
    }
  }
`;
```

And finally call it like this:

```
let date = "2020-01-08";
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ACTIVITY, {
  variables: {
    date
  }
});
```

More about queries: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries

Comment: I have the following error : "Unknown argument "date" on field "activities" of type "Query"."

Comment: I want to use the fetching by "where : json"

Comment: There is no `where` in apollo, can you share your schema definition of `Activity` ?